# How to format different date cells into the same format?

Tags: excel

I have a column in which there is not a consistent formatting of the date cells.

Specifically, I have so far observed two cases:

Case A: `1/30/14 20:00`

Case B: `1-8-2015 9:00`

Case B seems not to react to being transformed to a date format (i.e., it is most likely a string). Case A is in a proper date format which I can modify.

My idea was to simply do a ctrl+f and replace "`/`" with "`-`" and then copy paste it into a new worksheet as unicoded text (this didnt work because of the year difference).

I am also unsure whether this would be a consistent way of dealing with it. Are there any other known methods that can provide a more robust and consistent way of handling this type of formatting?

Comment: Do you just need all `-` to become `/`? Or is the `mm-dd-yy` part different? You could use `=Substitute(A1,"-","/")` to replace the `-`

Comment: Is "1-8-2015 9:00" referring to August 1st or January 8th in this scenario?

Comment: @BruceWayne No the issue is that the year is also different. See 14 vs 2015. So I think I need a way to actually read the date from that string.

Comment: @TimEdwards August 1st

Comment: I'm guessing it's down to local settings, if I have Case B it recognises it fine, if I put that in as text and then in another cell reference that with the `DATEVALUE` formula. If I use Case A this doesn't work at all. If your data only contains the two different formats and they're consistent then you'll have to do some string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using the `datevalue` function which tries to convert a string into a proper date.  It errors if it is given a number (an actual date) so I would use the following formula.  If it sees a number instead of a string it just returns the cell value.

```
=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(A1),A1)
```